# Installing Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: installation

In Win Xp Firefox ,Google Chrome and IE crash very often (Due to some virus or something else).

My friend suggested I should install Ubuntu Operating System (As it is unaffected by most viruses).

Now My question is If I Install Ubuntu along with windows on the same Hard Disk - will it slow my computer even more because 2 Operating Systems are in the computer..or will it solve my problem.

Also Should I install Ubuntu 10.04 or Ubuntu 12.04

**System Specs**

> AMD Sempron processor
>
> 2.21 Ghz 790 MB of RAM

Answer (score 3):

Normally installing new os won't effect existing os, so you can install ubuntu without any fear

Your system specifications are not enough to run ubuntu 12.04 smoothly . So I would like to suggest Lubuntu for your pc

Answer (score 1):

No issues installing/running two OS on same HDD. but before you do that be careful with your data in windows. you need to partition the HDD. suggest if possible to upgrade RAM to minmum 1 GB.(2G is recommended).
You will find ubuntu to be faster than your existing OS.
Hope that helps.